# How to take date through google voice input in dd/mm/yyyy format?

Tags: java, android

I want to take the date as a text from the user through google voice input.
So when user says:

> 8 July 2022

Then it will splits that string in `dd-mm-yyyy` format. How to get it?
Should I use any other method to get the date through speech input?

```java
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == 100) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
            ArrayList<String> result = data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);

            String date = result.get(0);

            date =   date.replace("january", "1");
            date =   date.replace("february", "2");
            date =   date.replace("march", "3");
            date =   date.replace("april", "4");
            date =   date.replace("may", "5");
            date =   date.replace("june", "6");
            date =   date.replace("july", "7");
            date =   date.replace("august", "8");
            date =   date.replace("september", "9");
            date =   date.replace("october", "10");
            date =   date.replace("november", "11");
            date =   date.replace("december", "12");
            String day = date.substring(1, 2);
            String month = date.substring(2, 7);
            String year = date.substring(date.length() - 4);
            String year1 = year.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z]", "");

            mDatebtn.setText(day + "-" + month + "-" + year1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are better off using a `DateTimeFormatter` which is able to do this job, but less brittle. For instance, you could parse into a `LocalDate` with the pattern `d MMMM uuuu` and then format using the pattern `dd-MM-uuuu`.

Comment: Yes. its less brittle. By using {DateTimeFormatter} not getting correct output.

Comment: Can you show us your use of a `DateTimeFormatter` which produces incorrect output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can use `java.time`, you can have the conversion without manipulating `String`s.

You will be needing

- two `DateTimeFormatter`s

  - one that handles the input `String` and
  - a second one that handles the format of the desired output/result
- a `LocalDate` to represent the values of the date to be converted

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // spoken date
    String userWords = "8 July 2022";
    // prepare two DateTimeFormatters, one for parsing the user's words and
    DateTimeFormatter dtfParse = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(
                                                    "d MMMM uuuu",
                                                    Locale.ENGLISH);
    // a second one to be used in order to format the desired result
    DateTimeFormatter dtfFormat = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(
                                                    "dd-MM-uuuu",
                                                    Locale.ENGLISH);
    // parse the input with the first formatter
    LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse(userWords, dtfParse);
    // and print it formatted by the second one
    System.out.println(localDate.format(dtfFormat));
}
```

Output of this code:

```
08-07-2022
```

Comment: Is it same applicable for time too? If user words 11 2 AM then?

Comment: Sure @RishiFf , but you will need a different class (`LocalTime`) and a different pattern for parsing (`"h m a"` for single-digit hour of day and minute of hour).

Comment: Ohk . Can you check once this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72960914/caused-by-java-time-format-datetimeparseexception-text-11-2-am-could-not-be

Comment: See my answer there… @RishiFf

Comment: yes. I am doing with your code.