# Caused by: java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '11 2 AM' could not be parsed at index 3

Tags: java, android, java-8, java-time

I want parse the time in hh:mm:a format. but when I passed the string in hh:m:a format it gives error java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: at index 3.
for example:- when I passed the string like 11:15 AM everything is fine. but when I passed the String in 11:2 AM. It says Text '11 2 AM' could not be parsed at index 3.

Here is my java code:-

```java
String time = result.get(0);
time = time.replace("a.m", "AM");
time = time.replace("p.m", "PM");
time = time.substring(0, time.length() - 1);

mTimebtn.setText(time);

if (time.contains("AM")) {
    DateTimeFormatter dtfParse1 = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("hh m a", Locale.ENGLISH);
    // a second one to be used in order to format the desired result
    DateTimeFormatter dtfFormat1 =  DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("hh:mm a", Locale.ENGLISH);
    LocalDate localDate1 = LocalDate.parse(time, 
    mTimebtn.setText(localDate1.format(dtfFormat1));

    finaltime = localDate1.format(dtfFormat1);
}
```

Comment: Why? because I am taking the input string through google voice input. so it needs some explicit characters.

Comment: I suggest you educate the publisher of your data about the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard for date-time formats. These are used by default in the *java.time* classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
try {
     String time = "11 2 AM";
     String parsePatter = time.contains(":") ? "hh:mm a" : "hh m a";
     SimpleDateFormat parser = new SimpleDateFormat(parsePatter);
     Date date = parser.parse(time);

     // Result
     SimpleDateFormat resultParse = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a");
     String result = resultParse.format(date);
     System.out.println(result); // 11:02 AM
    } catch (Exception ex) {
       ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: I tried with this code. but it only prints 11 2 AM. not 11:02 AM. why?

Comment: Make sure you print the right variable.

Comment: No, no, no, no, when the OP is using java.time, the modern Java date and time API, please, please do not suggest going back to the old and very troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` class.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to parse some *time of day*, you will be needing a *`java.time.LocalTime`*, *not* a `LocalDate`.

In contrast to the old and outdated `java.util.Date`, a `LocalDate` represents a date consisting of day of month, month of year and year.

You are trying to parse a time of day, the pattern might even be working for it but you cannot create a `LocalDate` from information about hour of day, minute of hour and AM/PM. That won't be working…

The following code might be working for you:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // your example input String
    String someTime = "11 2 AM";
    // one dtf for parsing input
    DateTimeFormatter timeParser = DateTimeFormatter
                                    .ofPattern("K m a", Locale.ENGLISH);
    // another one for formatting as desired
    DateTimeFormatter timeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter
                                        .ofPattern("KK:mm a", Locale.ENGLISH);
    // parse using the parser
    LocalTime localTime = LocalTime.parse(someTime, timeParser);
    // print using the formatter
    System.out.println(localTime.format(timeFormatter));
}
```

Output:

```
11:02 AM
```

Answer (score 0):

To Convert in hh:mm:a format
any of the form will work for 11:22 AM or 11:2 AM

```
 val time = "11:22 AM"
        //  or
        val time2 = "11:2 AM"
        val parser = SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm a")
        val date = parser.parse(time2) as Date
        var format=parser.format(date)
```

Comment: No, no, no, no, when the OP is using java.time, the modern Java date and time API, please, please do not suggest going back to the old and very troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` class.

Answer (score -1):

You passed 11:2 AM but the format is hh m A.
The format should be hh:m A but if you wanted to use format(hh m A) you should pass 11 2 AM. And LocalDate you should pass the date too. Check my answer below:

```
String time = "2022-07-13 11:2 AM";
time = time.replace("a.m", "AM");
time = time.replace("p.m", "PM");
System.out.println("Init:" + time);
if (time.contains("AM")) {
   DateTimeFormatter dtfParse1 = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd hh:m a",
                    Locale.ENGLISH);
            // a second one to be used in order to format the desired result
            DateTimeFormatter dtfFormat1 = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("hh:mm a", Locale.ENGLISH);
            LocalDateTime localDate1 = LocalDateTime.parse(time, dtfParse1);
            System.out.println(localDate1);
            //mDatebtn.setText(day + "-" + month + "-" + year);
            System.out.println(localDate1.format(dtfFormat1));
            //finaltime = localDate1.format(dtfFormat1);
        }
```

Comment: No. this answer is not useful. Still I'm getting same exception.

Comment: Can you show me you code?

Comment: `DateTimeFormatter dtfParse1 = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(
                                        "hh:m a",
                                        Locale.ENGLISH);
                                // a second one to be used in order to format the desired result
                                DateTimeFormatter dtfFormat1 = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(
                                        "hh:mm a",
                                        Locale.ENGLISH);
                                LocalDate localDate1 = LocalDate.parse(time, dtfParse1);`

Comment: Try to added date format too. You can check above code

Comment: It's LocalDate. Change to LocalDateTime. Follow my code above

Comment: but i want only time. Why should I pass date format then?

Comment: It's because the class is LocalDate it required date not time. If you want to get time you have to use LocalDateTime. You can just pass fixed date and concat with your time.

Comment: You can try my sample

Comment: Ohk. I will try. But will it affect when time is 11:15 AM format (hh:mm a)?

Comment: It work fine with this format too just try my sample

Comment: I tried with your code. still i am getting same error.

Comment: Just make sure the format dtfParse1 is the same format to your pass data

Comment: DateTimeFormatter dtfParse1 = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd hh:m a",
                    Locale.ENGLISH); this format?

Comment: yes. I tried in same format but it does not parse it?

Comment: Actually I am passing string in random format not in dd-mm-yyyy.

Comment: You can show me the string you can random

Comment: So like i am passing the time through google voice input. that's why I'm using                         `String time = result.get(0);` in my code.

Comment: String time = "2022-07-13 " + result.get(0)

Comment: You can try this with my format

Comment: No. its not working. Now it says `Caused by: java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '13-7-202211 2 AM' could not be parsed at index 5`

Comment: You forgot space

Comment: String time = "2022-07-13 " + result.get(0); and format should be "yyyy-MM-dd hh m a"

Comment: No. its not working

Comment: Maybe should try to change different logic to format the time.

Comment: I left the new answer with different logic you can try. :)